# blockchain scanning

Tags: blockchain, signature

Hello friends please let me know that is there any script that can scan the entire blockchain and extract the signature values and find the match of given input.

lets suppose i give the input "eb2dsa"

script has to scan all blocks and hashes for the given input

if found print the output in a text file with hash of transaction as well as the matching signature and the public key

Comment: Don't think there is any script like that, you'll probably have to write it yourself.

Comment: What is your input? Is it a pubkey? Can you not transform your input into an address and plug it into a block explorer?

Comment: my input would be a signature, script has to scan all blockchain blocks for similar signatures and print output to file with TXID address and input matching signature